# Grouping speech files by speaker

Tags: audio-recording

I am looking for a program that can take as input a set of speech files, and group these speech files by speaker (or in some way identified which speech files have been produced by the same speaker).

Any license, price, and operating system is fine.

Example of speech file corpus (with no speaker ID provided): https://common-voice-data-download.s3.amazonaws.com/cv_corpus_v1.tar.gz